# How to put more than one relational id in one column mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

suppose that I have two tables first of them is :

```
   Course table  
   ----------------
   |id | name     |
   |0  | pr course|
   |1  | science  |
   ----------------
```

and the other is :

```
Teacher table 
----------------------
|id | name | Courses |
|0  | mark | 0 ,1    |
|1 | john | 0        |
----------------------
```

I want to put in the course column the id's of courses which the teacher gives 
to use them in join statement  .
what is the best method to do something like that . 
I hope that i was clear enough and thank you.

Comment: show sample value  please ..

Comment: And your current query attempt!

Comment: the value doesn't matter the idea is that i don't know the number of courses that i have and each teacher will take a different number of those courses

Comment: How tables are related? `Teacher.Id` = `Course.Id`? Provide sample data and desired results. Unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: `the value doesn't matter` -> It does for us to understand the question clearly. So please create some sample data and expected output based on that.

Comment: ok I edited the post

Comment: ok. Now what do you want as output?

Comment: Can one Course be related to many Teachers? If yes, you need many to many relationship (and additional table). If no, then you should add column teacher_id to Course table. It's bad idea to keep many ids in one field (like Courses in Teacher table).

Comment: The problem is that you store comma separated values. Never, ever do that - it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Don't do it.... normalize your data properly, otherwise you'll be plagued by complex code issues and slow performance (like if you want to list the teachers who teach course 1); create a CourseTeachers cross-reference table instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are designing your database breaks the [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) which says that every attribute of your database should be atomic.
Typically, the `Courses`column is not atomic because it is a list.

You need to create a new table like `GivenBy` that look like

```
   GivenBy table  
   ------------------------
   |course_id | teacher_id|
   ------------------------
```

In this table, the Primary Key is composed of the 2 columns (course_id and teacher_id). Each row stores one relation between a teacher and a course.
Finally, you should have Foreign Keys referencing the id's of `Course` and `Teacher`

Comment: Glad it helps. 
I would recommend you to take a look a the other [Normal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#List_of_Normal_Forms) that exist to help you design your database

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to add a third table which handles the teacher-course Relation.

```
TeachersCourses table
----------------------
|teacher_id|course_id|
----------------------
```

Then you can use your join-statement on this table. Don't try to put more then one value (especially no keys) in one column.

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible way to store comma-separated values, but if you don't have ability to change It, you could try something like.

**QUERY**

```
select t.name as TeacherName, c.name as CourseName
from Teacher t
inner join Courses c
    on ',' + t.id + ',' like '%,' + cast(c.id as nvarchar(20)) + ',%'
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table Courses
(
    id nvarchar(60),
    name nvarchar(60)
)
insert into Courses values (0 ,'pr course'), (1 ,'science')     

create table Teacher
(
   id nvarchar(60),
   name nvarchar(60),
   courses nvarchar(60)
)
insert into Teacher values (0,'mark','0,1'), (1,'john','0'  )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TeacherName     CourseName
mark            pr course
john            science*
```

Comment: Great for the full table scan because it can't be indexed

Comment: And if you have to work with comma-separated lists of IDs, then FIND_IN_SET() is MySQL's built-in function to optimise it as much as it can be optimised